# Gradle build: file not found error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm running into this error when I try to build my project with Gradle:

```
${path_to_project}\teacher\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugAndroidTestResources\merged.dir\values-w270dp-h560dp-v13\values-w270dp-h560dp-v13.xml: error: file not found.
```

I'm really confused because I opened the file and it seems like it's from a dependecy I'm using: `com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.4.1`

Here's the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="mdtp_selected_calendar_layout_height">230dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mdtp_selected_date_day_size">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mdtp_selected_date_height">190dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mdtp_selected_date_month_size">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mdtp_selected_date_year_size">30dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I encountered an error kind of like this before with a previous plugin before, but missing resource was from the **appcompat-v7** library and was because I had a mismatch with the appcompat-v7 library version and my **compileSdkVersion**. All I had to do was update my appcompat-v7 and compileSdkVersion to the latest versions and all was set.

But this instance seems to be from a third party library and I'm using the latest version of the library. I don't know how to go about fixing this

Comment: Did you try to remove your build folder and rebuild your project after?

Comment: No. I'll try that now

Comment: @SabriMeviş Tried that. It didn't work

Comment: Just saying this as a side note, Android already has a built-in material design DateTimePicker... what is the purpose of using a third party when there is already one in Android?

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, I know. That's what I would have used normally. A client gave me an app and asked me to fix the gradle errors that were popping up, but she told me not to change the core systems and dependencies cos she's still going to give it back to the original developer to manage and whatever. Plus the code is just really disorganized and uncommented, and it seems like it was written in 2016 or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the library dependency on another project and it built smoothly. Moreover, the file you have provided is in valid XML format. So, make sure you have the latest android build tools and library version to ensure you *don't cast stones against the wind*. Which are

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.0'
}
```

And from the  `MaterialDateTimePicker/gradle.properties`

```
VERSION_NAME=3.5.0
...
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.2
```

Now given the issue persists, from within your project directory you could run (prepend `./` for Unix)

```
gradlew clean assemble
```

to see, if it builds correctly over a clean base without any leftover artifacts. As a last resort, given it still doesn't, you could use the stacktrace thereof to report it as an issue at its [GitHub's MaterialDateTimePicker issues](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/issues).

Comment: This worked. I don't know if it was the dependency upgrade from **3.4.1** to **3.5.0** or the buildTools upgrade from **27.0.1** to **27.0.2** or the `gradlew clean assemble` command, but somehow this fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar issue two days ago, here is my solution.

Replace your dependency

```
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.4.1'
```

to

```
compile ('com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.4.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

That worked for me!

Comment: I just tried that. It didn't work for me. It's still giving the same error. :(

Comment: where do you placed it?

Answer (score 1):

inside `values-w270dp-h560dp`

`dimens.xml` should be, you can manually add this file:

```
<resources
    xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <dimen name="mdtp_selected_calendar_layout_height">230dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mdtp_selected_date_height">190dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mdtp_selected_date_year_size">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mdtp_selected_date_day_size">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mdtp_selected_date_month_size">30dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

edit: just checked the library, seems like the current version is

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your targeted and compile sdk version

> compileSdkVersion 23
>       buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.onsource"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
```

check with your SDK and also check gradle version e.g. 2.3.3 if still issue provide your SDK version info

Answer (score 0):

Can you put below code in your app's main build.gradle file and sync project.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'  }

        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting these errors when the project name was very long, and the location I was saving the project in, added to it. That apparently caused some files to be missing. Moving the project to another location so that the file names are not crossing the system limit resolved the errors for me.